# what does "it" refer to in this sentence "...by those whose culture it is"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a sentence from an LSAT:

> According to one proposed definition, a culture is the totality of the
> customs practiced by those whose culture it is.

Could someone please explain what does "it" refer to?

Thank you very much,

Leon

Comment: According to one proposed definition, a culture is the totality of the customs practiced by those whose culture the totality of the customs is.

Comment: It's non-referential so it doesn't refer to anything.  A meaningless pronoun, cf. "it is their culture".

Comment: @BillJ I see your point but is there any discussion related to this on CaGEL? Can you please give me page no?

Comment: At the same time, I can see why people think that "it" refers to "the culture", so it is a bit tricky I guess. I wish there was some kind of discussion in the book.

Comment: @BillJ Another doubt "...whose culture it is", is this an example of extraposition?

Answer (score 3):

If you concentrate on the relative clause

> [those] ***whose*** culture ***it*** is

You could rewrite it as a main clause in this way:

> It is their culture.

So ***it*** here is a personal pronoun referring to ***their culture***. You could replace "it" with "this" referring to the same:

> This is their culture.

You can also have similarly structured sentences with other personal pronouns:

> I am their teacher. (so in your specific sentence, the similar construction would be ***whose teacher I am***)

Answer (score 3):

It refers to "a culture". The definition is self-referential.

> a culture is the totality of the customs practiced by those whose culture it is.

Perhaps it will be clearer to substitute a specific culture, such as Arstotzkan (a fictional culture).

Direct substitution:

> Arstotzkan is the totality of the customs practiced by those whose culture Arstotzkan is.

although we would swap the last two words because it sounds more natural:

> Arstotzkan is the totality of the customs practiced by those whose culture is Arstotzkan.

Comment: quibble: it refers to "the culture", not "a culture", as there's already a culture in question, as is the way with pronouns other than indefinite ones

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to a specific culture.

The sentence refers to cultures (plural), but an individual can only 'have' one culture at a time, hence 'it' is singular.

Comment: An individual can have more than one culture. However, the sentence is describing one culture at a time.

Comment: I disagree - a person can be influenced by several cultures, can have "come from" several, but their own culture is unique to them, and fundamentally singular.